# How to read data fro Telosb sensors in Android Tablet (Lenovo)

Tags: android, sensors, tinyos

I would like to connect telosb sensor with my tablet and read the data from sensor. I am using Lenovo tablet (Android 3.1) but I am not able to find the correct driver for this. I tried to run the FTDI beta driver, but still the tablet doesn't recognize the device. FTDI website says that default permissions of USB device has to be modified and we need root access for it. I couldn't also root the tablet yet.

Has anyone worked on similar stuff?

Thanks,
Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Arduino boards to interface real world with your Android device?
Have a look at this [project](http://blog.bricogeek.com/noticias/arduino/el-adk-de-google-en-un-arduino-uno/). I think it can be related to what you want to do. This other [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-datalogger-for-your-wireless-sensor-networ/?ALLSTEPS) is more related to the TelosB device. Hope this can be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Both websites are working with Arduino board which I don't have it now. I was looking for a software solution but anyway this information was also useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html), Google has their own libraries to communicate with external devices.

Comment: Thanks Saravana,

I used the Android USB API (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) and it was successful.